# How to arrange a logo in the left corner and three spans in the right - reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to arrange three elements - a logo and three inscriptions.
I want the logo in the left corner and three spans below each other in the right corner.

My HTML (ReactJS) code and CSS:

```css
.spanContacts {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span> 
  <img src={logo} alt="Logo" width="230" height="70" />
</span>

<span className="spanContacts">
  <Facebook/>
</span>

<span className="spanContacts">
  E-mail: <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmail.com</a>
</span>

<span className="spanContacts">
  Телефон:  <a href="tel:+telephone number"> telephone number&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Hey Buddy, are you using a framework? Or is it plain html/css?

Comment: image logo & contact detail add in separate div and use different class & using css "float:left & float: right" you can arrange your content.

Comment: Give me example please